# Problems installing google ap engine for php

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I followed all the steps given here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/installingwindows
but when I open up localhost from my machine there is nothing displayed there.

Earlier I had installed it for python and it worked just fine.

log is

```
startupinfo.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
```

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW'
INFO     2013-11-23 00:42:54,742 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: ....

python path: C:\Python27\python.exe

App engine SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine

and deployment server is left blank.

Comment: First make sure, that you create Project in GAE...... 
Did you create any project???

Comment: yes i did create a project

Comment: Open the GAE click from EDIT menu click on Preferences and take a screen shot and upload it in the questions....

Comment: I cant post a picture my reputation is low...

Comment: send me request at sulemannbd@gmail.com

Comment: I have the same identical problem. I've installed all the required software as i already previously used Python 2.7 (32 bit). Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need to update your python to 2.7.2 up version.

I had the same problem today, and I found the following solution at last.

[Invalid PHP configuration error Google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614992/invalid-php-configuration-error-google-app-engine)

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10363

I use win7, google app engine for php, and after I download python 2.7.6 for windows x86, problem sovled.