# Invalid PHP configuration error Google app engine

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, installation

Followed the exact same steps as given here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/installingwindows
but when I open up localhost I get this error

```
'module' object has no attribute 'STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW'
```

and the title of the page says Invalid PHP Configuration.Also the path set for python executable is correctly set...

Answer (score 1):

Known issue which is being resolved (should be in 1.8.9 release).

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10363